# What are established and unestablished knights and knaves?

Tags: logic

I am reading *Games for your mind* by Jason Rosenhouse. In chapter 10, he defines established and unestablished knights and knaves: islanders bearing the label "established" can be thought of as having proved their identities.

Example (from puzzle 44). Anne says "I am not an established knight." If Anne were a knave, her statement would be true. Since knaves do not make true statements, we conclude that she is a knight, but not an established one.

What does it mean if a knight or a knave has or has not proved his/her identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "*proven*" is somewhat confusing.  I suspect that the author intends this term to represent that statements made by this particular islander, or other islanders, have **conclusively determined** whether this particular islander is a knight or a knave.

For example, if you walk up to an islander whose identity has not yet been established, and the islander says, "2+2 = 4", then the islander has just established that he is a knight.

Peculiarly, there is *something of a flaw* in the analysis of the islander's statement of :

"I am not an established knight.".

As discussed, this statement could not have been made by a knave.  Therefore, at the time that the islander (who must be a knight) had this **thought**, the idea was **truthful**.

However, at the moment that the islander finished speaking the sentence, the sentence *became a falsehood*, since the act of speaking the sentence **established** that the islander was a knight and thus **affected** whether the spoken sentence was true or not.

This is similar to, but somewhat different from the notion of *meta-statements*, such as

"This statement is a lie".

The assumption that such a statement is true leads to a contradiction.  Similarly, the assumption that such a statement is false also leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Can I interpret an unestablished knight as someone who has the knight spirit but has never said anything since born?

Comment: @HaoranChen Not necessarily.  Suppose that the knight has said "The Reimann hypothesis" is true.  At this point, one could argue that the knight has not yet established himself, because no one knows whether the knight has just lied or has just told the truth.  There is also the issue of whether a knight can be **retroactively** established.  Suppose that 5 years after the knight makes that statement, some Mathematician proves that the Reimann hypothesis is true.  Does this mean that the knight is *retroactively established*?

Comment: OK. Let's assume there is no prophet. Then after he said "The Riemann hypothesis is true", he could not make any other announcement since then, as any proved or unproved announcement might violate his identity. For example, if he says 2+2=4 and the RH is false, then it is contradictory, right? He cannot say "The Goldbach conjecture is true", either, as one might be true and the other might be false?

Comment: @HaoranChen It depends on how you interpret the constraint "*knights always tell the truth*".  Does this mean the **actual truth**, consistent with the real world, or does this merely signify the truth, "*to the best of their knowledge at the time of the statement*".   This distinction is typically overlooked in Math/Logic puzzles, because the puzzle typically only involves statements whose truth or falsity is well known to the speaker, at the time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have better understanding now.